# How do I get values from components added by for each in svelte?

Tags: typescript, frontend, svelte

I'm new to front end and svelte and experimenting with some things.

I have the following counter component that has increment/decrement button for the items:

Counter.svelte

```
<script>
    export let amount = 0;
    function increment() {
        amount += 1;
    }

    function decrement() {
        if (amount > 0) {
            amount -= 1;
        }
    }
</script>


<button on:click={decrement}>-</button>{amount}<button on:click={increment}>+</button>
```

App.svelte

```
<script>
... import stuff

    let items=[{ //data from rest
      id: 1,
      name: potato,
      price: 5
    }, {
      id: 2,
      name: garlic,
      price: 3
    }, {
      id: 3,
      name: rice,
      price: 10
    }];

    function purchase() {
        //TODO use JSON generated in POST
    }
</script>

{#each items as item}
    {item.name} <Counter></Counter>
{/each}

<button on:click={purchase}>Purchase</button>
```

How do I generate the following JSON, when the amount selected for the item is not 0 after I click the button? (assuming garlic amount is 0)

```
    [{
      id: 1,
      name: potato,
      price: 5,
      amount: 30
    },{
      id: 3,
      name: rice,
      price: 10,
      amount: 400
    }];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to bind a value inside the `#each` loop to a property of the single `item`

```html
{#each items as item}
    {item.name} <Counter bind:amount={item.amount}/>
{/each}
```

The property doesn't exist yet but since you have a default value set inside `Counter`

```
export let amount = 0;
```

it will be initialized with zero. All changes to the amounts will then change `items` directly. So inside `purchase` just filter `items` for the ones with an amount

```
    function purchase() {
        const itemsWithAmount = items.filter(i => i.amount > 0)
        console.log(itemsWithAmount)
    }
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/e4dce944bdc34368895dc7143eaa4182?version=3.55.0)

```
<script>
    import Counter from './Counter.svelte'

    let items=[{
        id: 1,
        name: 'potato',
        price: 5
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'garlic',
        price: 3
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'rice',
        price: 10
    }];

    $: console.log(items)

    function purchase() {
        const itemsWithAmount = items.filter(i => i.amount !== 0)
        console.log(itemsWithAmount)
    }
</script>

<ul>
    {#each items as item}
    <li>
        {item.name} <Counter bind:amount={item.amount}/>
    </li>
    {/each}
</ul>

<button on:click={purchase}>Purchase</button>
```

Comment: wow I can't believe it was that simple. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You probably would want to initialize the `amount` property of all the items to `0` after getting the data, then it can be bound to the `Counter`:

```html
<Counter bind:amount={item.amount} />
```

`bind` propagates changes from the component to the item objects.

In `purchase` you then just have to filter the items, something like:

```
const toBuy = items.filter(x => x.amount > 0);
```