# How to retrieve values from components added by for each in svelte when using data from rest in iteration?

Tags: typescript, frontend, svelte

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74990715/how-do-i-get-values-from-components-added-by-for-each-in-svelte/) before now I modified it to use the rest service to retrieve item list. It works when the data is hardcoded but I'm getting undefined when using data from rest.

Counter.svelte

```
<script>
    export let amount = 0;
    function increment() {
        amount += 1;
    }

    function decrement() {
        if (amount > 0) {
            amount -= 1;
        }
    }
</script>


<button on:click={decrement}>-</button>{amount}<button on:click={increment}>+</button>
```

Updated app.svelte to use rest service in creating component

App.svelte

```
<script>
... import stuff

    let items;

    onMount( async() => {getItems()});
    function getItemsFromDB() {
      const getItems = (async() => {
        'MY_REST_API",
        {method:'GET'}
      });
      const data = await response.json();
      items=data;
    }
/*
items contains this:
    [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'potato',
        price: 5
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'garlic',
        price: 3
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'rice',
        price: 10
    }];
*/

    function purchase() {
        const itemsWithAmount = items.filter(i => i.amount !== 0)
        console.log(itemsWithAmount)
    }
</script>

<ul>
    {#each items as item}
    <li>
        {item.name} <Counter bind:amount={item.amount}/> <-- **UNDEFINED in page**
    </li>
    {/each}
</ul>

<button on:click={purchase}>Purchase</button>
```

I'm getting undefined on the counter value after the page renders

expected json:

```
    [{
      id: 1,
      name: potato,
      price: 5,
      amount: 30
    },{
      id: 3,
      name: rice,
      price: 10,
      amount: 400
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in the example code, i'll limit my answer to asynchronous code, which can cause the `undefined`.

The `{#each}` block is rendered before the component is mounted and before the api responds.

I've found using [{#await}](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-await) to be useful when working with promises.

```
<script>
async function getItems() {
  const response = await apiStuff()
  return await response.json();
}
</script>

{#await getItems() then items}
  <ul>
    {#each items as item}
      <li>
        {item.name} <Counter bind:amount={item.amount}/>
      </li>
    {/each}
  </ul>

  <button on:click={() => purchase(items)}>Purchase</button>
{/await}
```

A downside is that the items array is not directly available in the `<script>` section.

Another option would be to to initialize `let items;` to an empty array.
`let items = [];`.
As the each first render the empty array and when the items are updated with the