# How to 'wait' for fetch to finish before assigning value in Svelte?

Tags: typescript, svelte

I have the following code in svelte that retrieves list of items from the backend:

```
<script>
../ import stuff
let items;

const getItems = async() => {
  const resp = await fetch('localhost:8080/items');
  const result = await resp.json();
  items = result;
}
onMount(async() => {getItems()})

$: totalPrice = items.filter(i => i.amount !== 0).reduce((sum,obj) => {return (sum+obj)},0);  <--- error here in runtime

</script>

    function purchase() {
       //do stuff
    }
```

Counter.svelte

```
<script>
    export let amount = 0;
    function increment() {
        amount += 1;
    }

    function decrement() {
        if (amount > 0) {
            amount -= 1;
        }
    }
</script>

<p>{totalPrice}</p>

<button on:click={decrement}>-</button>{amount}<button on:click={increment}>+</button>
```

sample data from the backend:

```
    let items=[{
        id: 1,
        name: 'potato',
        price: 5
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'garlic',
        price: 3
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: 'rice',
        price: 10
    }];
```

sample data when I add amount on an item.

```
[ { id: 3 ,
  name: "rice" ,
  price: 10 ,
  amount: 3 
}]
```

I need the totalPrice to dynamically change so I assigned it with filter and reduce array but I'm getting undefined error on startup. How do I make the assignment 'wait' for the service to finish on start up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that you initialize `items` with undefined and call `.filter()`/`.reduce()` on that. Similar as to in [this question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74999697/how-to-retrieve-values-from-components-added-by-for-each-in-svelte-when-using-da) either initialize with an empty array

```
<script>
    import{itemsWithAmount} from './itemsWithAmount'
    import {onMount} from 'svelte'

    let items = []

    onMount(fetchItems) 

    async function fetchItems() {
        // ...
        items = itemsWithAmount
    }

    $: totalPrice = items.reduce((sum,item) => sum + item.amount * item.price, 0);

</script>

{totalPrice}
```

or change to an `#await` block and the totalPrice calculation from a reactive variable to function with items as parameter. The value will be recalculated every time `items` change

```
<script>
    import{itemsWithAmount} from './itemsWithAmount'

    async function fetchItems() {
        // ...
        return itemsWithAmount
    }

    function totalPrice(items) {
        return items.reduce((sum,item) => sum + item.amount * item.price, 0);
    }

</script>

{#await fetchItems() then items}
    {totalPrice(items)}
{/await}
```

For simplicity the items in both cases directly with the amount

Notice the change in the calculation of the `totalPrice`. You want to sum up the products of the item's amount with its price. If the amount is zero, the product will be zero. No problem adding zero, so the filter step is unnecessary

A [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/41288cee6a5d476482656c1ee614650c?version=3.55.0) with both option